# Import same class globally

Tags: java, matlab, import

I have a function file called `getFeatures.m` that looks like:

```
function [features] getFeatures()
  % Import the XPath classes
  import javax.xml.xpath.*
    % other code  
end
function [name] = getName()
  % Import the XPath classes
  import javax.xml.xpath.*
    % other code
end
```

As you can see, both functions import xpath library, since I have a lot of functions that need to import that class how can I do this a single time?

Comment: Why don't you put the import out of the functions?

Answer (score 2):

I have stumbled upon the same problem. My personal (and ugly!) workaround for this is defining a method that performs the imports; you will still have to call that function, but at least it groups the imports at a single place, albeit inside strings.

```
function cmd  = initJava()
    cmd = 'import package.*';
    if nargout == 0
        warning('off','MATLAB:Java:DuplicateClass');
        evalin('caller',cmd);
        warning('on','MATLAB:Java:DuplicateClass');
    end;
end
```

This can be called either as `initJava()` or `eval(initJava())`. If I remember correctly the first one doesn't always do what it's supposed to do, but you'll have to test that yourself.

If someone has a better/nicer/other solution, I'm very interested in hearing that one.